# Is this tense form correct here or has the writer erred?

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions

> If the larger picture of ancient forager life is hard to reconstruct, particular events are largely irretrievable. When a Sapiens band first entered a valley inhabited by Neanderthals, the following years might have witnessed a breathtaking historical drama. **Unfortunately**, nothing **would have** survived from such an encounter except, at best, a few fossilised bones and a handful of stone tools...

Why has the writer here used **would have** instead of **has**?

We use this form when conjecturing or hypothesising, right? Shouldn't it be **Unfortunately, nothing has survived...**?

Answer (score 2):

Because the entire paragraph is hypothetical.  We don't know if there was such an encounter, so the author is talking about what **might** have happened: nothing *would have* survived *if* this did happen.

Comment: I found no better answer that this one... It is all an **assumption**, not a fact to be exact about it

Comment: Thank you, @Stangdon. But why hasn't the writer then chosen to write *When a Sapiens band  **would have** first entered a valley...*, as well?

Comment: @User40475 I think the short answer is simply "because that's not how we write hypotheticals in English".  *When they would have Xed* doesn't really make sense; we just say *When they Xed*.

Comment: I agree it is clunky writing if it were expressed that way. Thank you.